# HTTP POST 400 Error with Strapi and Sendgrid

Tags: reactjs, api, email, sendgrid, strapi

I am doing a udemy course and with it has a part where you can automatically send a confirmation e-mail once the user has submitted their details on the checkout form using strapi/sendgrid.

When I hit submit, all the data gets sent correctly, although an error message comes up and no e-mail is sent. The pop up box says [Object, object] and in the console the error message looks like this:

```
data: [{messages: [{id: "Auth.form.error.email.invalid"}]}]
0: {messages: [{id: "Auth.form.error.email.invalid"}]}
error: "Bad Request"
message: [{messages: [{id: "Auth.form.error.email.invalid"}]}]
0: {messages: [{id: "Auth.form.error.email.invalid"}]}
statusCode: 400
```

My checkout component looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
// prettier-ignore
import { Container, Box, Button, Heading, Text, TextField, Modal, Spinner } from "gestalt";
// prettier-ignore
import { Elements, StripeProvider, CardElement, injectStripe } from 'react-stripe-elements';
import ToastMessage from "./ToastMessage";
import { getCart, calculatePrice, clearCart, calculateAmount } from "../utils";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Strapi from "strapi-sdk-javascript/build/main";
const apiUrl = process.env.API_URL || "http://localhost:8082";
const strapi = new Strapi(apiUrl);

class _CheckoutForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    cartItems: [],
    address: "",
    postalCode: "",
    city: "",
    confirmationEmailAddress: "",
    toast: false,
    toastMessage: "",
    orderProcessing: false,
    modal: false
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ cartItems: getCart() });
  }

  handleChange = ({ event, value }) => {
    event.persist();
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: value });
  };

  handleConfirmOrder = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (this.isFormEmpty(this.state)) {
      this.showToast("Fill in all fields");
      return;
    }

    this.setState({ modal: true });
  };

  handleSubmitOrder = async () => {
    const {
      cartItems,
      city,
      address,
      postalCode,
      confirmationEmailAddress
    } = this.state;

    const amount = calculateAmount(cartItems);
    // Process order
    this.setState({ orderProcessing: true });
    let token;
    try {
      const response = await this.props.stripe.createToken();
      token = response.token.id;
      await strapi.createEntry("orders", {
        amount,
        brews: cartItems,
        city,
        postalCode,
        address,
        token
      });
      await strapi.request("POST", "/email", {
        data: {
          to: confirmationEmailAddress,
          subject: `Order Confirmation - BrewHaha ${new Date(Date.now())}`,
          text: "Your order has been processed",
          html: "<bold>Expect your order to arrive in 2-3 shipping days</bold>"
        }
      });
      this.setState({ orderProcessing: false, modal: false });
      clearCart();
      this.showToast("Your order has been successfully submitted!", true);
    } catch (err) {
      this.setState({ orderProcessing: false, modal: false });
      this.showToast(err.message);
    }
  };

  isFormEmpty = ({ address, postalCode, city, confirmationEmailAddress }) => {
    return !address || !postalCode || !city || !confirmationEmailAddress;
  };

  showToast = (toastMessage, redirect = false) => {
    this.setState({ toast: true, toastMessage });
    setTimeout(
      () =>
        this.setState(
          { toast: false, toastMessage: "" },
          // if true passed to 'redirect' argument, redirect home
          () => redirect && this.props.history.push("/")
        ),
      5000
    );
  };

  closeModal = () => this.setState({ modal: false });

  render() {
    // prettier-ignore
    const { toast, toastMessage, cartItems, modal, orderProcessing } = this.state;

    return (
      <Container>
        <Box
          color="darkWash"
          margin={4}
          padding={4}
          shape="rounded"
          display="flex"
          justifyContent="center"
          alignItems="center"
          direction="column"
        >
          {/* Checkout Form Heading */}
          <Heading color="midnight">Checkout</Heading>
          {cartItems.length > 0 ? (
            <React.Fragment>
              {/* User Cart */}
              <Box
                display="flex"
                justifyContent="center"
                alignItems="center"
                direction="column"
                marginTop={2}
                marginBottom={6}
              >
                <Text color="darkGray" italic>
                  {cartItems.length} Items for Checkout
                </Text>
                <Box padding={2}>
                  {cartItems.map(item => (
                    <Box key={item._id} padding={1}>
                      <Text color="midnight">
                        {item.name} x {item.quantity} - $
                        {item.quantity * item.price}
                      </Text>
                    </Box>
                  ))}
                </Box>
                <Text bold>Total Amount: {calculatePrice(cartItems)}</Text>
              </Box>
              {/* Checkout Form */}
              <form
                style={{
                  display: "inlineBlock",
                  textAlign: "center",
                  maxWidth: 450
                }}
                onSubmit={this.handleConfirmOrder}
              >
                {/* Shipping Address Input */}
                <TextField
                  id="address"
                  type="text"
                  name="address"
                  placeholder="Shipping Address"
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                {/* Postal Code Input */}
                <TextField
                  id="postalCode"
                  type="text"
                  name="postalCode"
                  placeholder="Postal Code"
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                {/* City Input */}
                <TextField
                  id="city"
                  type="text"
                  name="city"
                  placeholder="City of Residence"
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                {/* Confirmation Email Address Input */}
                <TextField
                  id="confirmationEmailAddress"
                  type="email"
                  name="confirmationEmailAddress"
                  placeholder="Confirmation Email Address"
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                {/* Credit Card Element */}
                <CardElement
                  id="stripe__input"
                  onReady={input => input.focus()}
                />
                <button id="stripe__button" type="submit">
                  Submit
                </button>
              </form>
            </React.Fragment>
          ) : (
            // Default Text if No Items in Cart
            <Box color="darkWash" shape="rounded" padding={4}>
              <Heading align="center" color="watermelon" size="xs">
                Your Cart is Empty
              </Heading>
              <Text align="center" italic color="green">
                Add some brews!
              </Text>
            </Box>
          )}
        </Box>
        {/* Confirmation Modal */}
        {modal && (
          <ConfirmationModal
            orderProcessing={orderProcessing}
            cartItems={cartItems}
            closeModal={this.closeModal}
            handleSubmitOrder={this.handleSubmitOrder}
          />
        )}
        <ToastMessage show={toast} message={toastMessage} />
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

const ConfirmationModal = ({
  orderProcessing,
  cartItems,
  closeModal,
  handleSubmitOrder
}) => (
  <Modal
    accessibilityCloseLabel="close"
    accessibilityModalLabel="Confirm Your Order"
    heading="Confirm Your Order"
    onDismiss={closeModal}
    footer={
      <Box
        display="flex"
        marginRight={-1}
        marginLeft={-1}
        justifyContent="center"
      >
        <Box padding={1}>
          <Button
            size="lg"
            color="red"
            text="Submit"
            disabled={orderProcessing}
            onClick={handleSubmitOrder}
          />
        </Box>
        <Box padding={1}>
          <Button
            size="lg"
            text="Cancel"
            disabled={orderProcessing}
            onClick={closeModal}
          />
        </Box>
      </Box>
    }
    role="alertdialog"
    size="sm"
  >
    {/* Order Summary */}
    {!orderProcessing && (
      <Box
        display="flex"
        justifyContent="center"
        alignItems="center"
        direction="column"
        padding={2}
        color="lightWash"
      >
        {cartItems.map(item => (
          <Box key={item._id} padding={1}>
            <Text size="lg" color="red">
              {item.name} x {item.quantity} - ${item.quantity * item.price}
            </Text>
          </Box>
        ))}
        <Box paddingY={2}>
          <Text size="lg" bold>
            Total: {calculatePrice(cartItems)}
          </Text>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    )}

    {/* Order Processing Spinner */}
    <Spinner
      show={orderProcessing}
      accessibilityLabel="Order Processing Spinner"
    />
    {orderProcessing && (
      <Text align="center" italic>
        Submitting Order...
      </Text>
    )}
  </Modal>
);

const CheckoutForm = withRouter(injectStripe(_CheckoutForm));

const Checkout = () => (
  <StripeProvider apiKey="pk_test_F92R0PypgxxkAKVgMt7pH3Og00RQXrWC3T">
    <Elements>
      <CheckoutForm />
    </Elements>
  </StripeProvider>
);

export default Checkout;
```

My e-mail controller .js file looks like this:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Email.js controller
 *
 * @description: A set of functions called "actions" of the `email` plugin.
 */

const _ = require('lodash');

module.exports = {
  send: async ctx => {
    // Retrieve provider configuration.
    const config = await strapi
      .store({
        environment: strapi.config.environment,
        type: 'plugin',
        name: 'email',
      })
      .get({ key: 'provider' });

    // Verify if the file email is enable.
    if (config.enabled === false) {
      strapi.log.error('Email is disabled');
      return ctx.badRequest(null, [
        {
          messages: [
            { id: 'Email.status.disabled', message: 'Emails disabled' },
          ],
        },
      ]);
    }

    // Something is wrong
    if (ctx.status === 400) {
      return;
    }

    let options = ctx.request.body;

    // await strapi.plugins.email.services.email.send(options, config);
    try {
      // Send email to the user
      await strapi.plugins["email"].services.email.send({
        to: options.to,
        from: "test@example.com",
        subject: options.subject,
        text: options.text,
        html: options.html
      });
    } catch (err) {
      return ctx.badRequest(null, err);
    }


    // Send 200 `ok`
    ctx.send({});
  },

  getEnvironments: async ctx => {
    const environments = _.map(
      _.keys(strapi.config.environments),
      environment => {
        return {
          name: environment,
          active: strapi.config.environment === environment,
        };
      }
    );

    ctx.send({ environments });
  },

  getSettings: async ctx => {
    let config = await strapi.plugins.email.services.email.getProviderConfig(
      ctx.params.environment
    );

    ctx.send({
      providers: strapi.plugins.email.config.providers,
      config,
    });
  },

  updateSettings: async ctx => {
    await strapi
      .store({
        environment: ctx.params.environment,
        type: 'plugin',
        name: 'email',
      })
      .set({ key: 'provider', value: ctx.request.body });

    ctx.send({ ok: true });
  },
};
```

I also have the correct API key from sendgrid in my strapi sendgrid e-mail settings.

Questions seem to take up to 6 months to get answered on the course, so a faster solution would be greatly appreciated.

Happy to provide more code if needed.

Thank you

Comment: can you show your `data` that you are sending in the post call to `/email` ?

Answer (score 0):

So this is a common issue with SendGrid. You need to go into your settings in Sendgrid and authorize your FROM sender. Once you follow those steps, and confirm the email, you should not receive this error anymore.
I've attached a picture to show you how to get there.
[Sendgrid sender auth steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqBck.png)